# Timer tick when the for loop is completed

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How can I tick the timer when the for loop is completed? I don't want to run the timer every X minute, I want to run the timer when the button is clicked and then just tick the timer again when the for loop is completed..

```
 For Each row As DataRow In MTProcessTable.Rows
  Try
            If checkKeyHelp(process.datain) Then
                msg = msgTable.Rows(1)(1).ToString()
                MsgBox(msg)
                writeMsg("1 MO help at ")

            ElseIf checkKeyInfo(process.datain) Then
                msg = msgTable.Rows(4)(1).ToString()
                MsgBox(msg)
                writeMsg("1 MO INFO at ")
            Else

                MOTable = selectMO(process.mo, process.mt)
                moRowNb = MOTable.Rows.Count()
                MO = New MO_class
                If moRowNb <> 0 Then
                    MOrow = MOTable.Rows(0)
                    MO.newuser = MOrow("newuser")
                    MO.sim_id = MOrow("sim_id")
                End If
       Catch ex As Exception
            logFile("executeTimer ----" & ex.Message)
            updateProcessed(process.id, ex.Message)
        Finally
            updateProcessed(process.id, msg)
        End Try
 Next row

Private Sub start_btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles start_btn.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    tm.StartTimer()
End Sub
```

Comment: why do you want a timer for that?

Comment: because when the timer starts, i'm filling a datatable and i'm executing some action on every row in the for loop and when the for loop is finished the function should start all over again and datatable is refilled with a different number of rows...so i can't know the time needed for the function to be completed because everytime i have different number of rows that's why i just need to tick the timer once the function has executed all the rows in the datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to write a program that will select data and process it. Once that is complete, you want to start the process over by selecting new data and processing that, etc. etc.

If you want to use a timer, I would set it up as follows. It will use a few shared items to start or stop the timer which runs the sub. One problem is that while it is running, the program will be unresponsive. The only time you can 'stop' the program is during the time in between runs. I have the time between threads set to 10 seconds (10000 ms), but you can use any value.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub RunProcess()
        'Add code to populate datatable
        For Each row As DataRow In MTProcessTable.Rows
            Try
                If checkKeyHelp(Process.datain) Then
                    msg = msgTable.Rows(1)(1).ToString()
                    MsgBox(msg)
                    writeMsg("1 MO help at ")

                ElseIf checkKeyInfo(Process.datain) Then
                    msg = msgTable.Rows(4)(1).ToString()
                    MsgBox(msg)
                    writeMsg("1 MO INFO at ")
                Else

                    MOTable = selectMO(Process.mo, Process.mt)
                    moRowNb = MOTable.Rows.Count()
                    MO = New MO_class
                    If moRowNb <> 0 Then
                        MOrow = MOTable.Rows(0)
                        MO.newuser = MOrow("newuser")
                        MO.sim_id = MOrow("sim_id")
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                logFile("executeTimer ----" & ex.Message)
                updateProcessed(Process.Id, ex.Message)
            Finally
                updateProcessed(Process.Id, msg)
            End Try
        Next row

        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Timer1 As Timer 'Create timer

    Sub Timer1_Tick() 'Handle timer tick
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        RunProcess()
    End Sub

    Private blRunning As Boolean

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1 = New Timer 'Create instance of timer
        Timer1.Interval = 10000 'Time in MS before starting next process
        AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick 'Add tick handler to timer
        Timer1.Enabled = blRunning 'Enable/disable timer
    End Sub

    Private Sub start_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles start_btn.Click
        If blRunning = True Then
            blRunning = False
            start_btn.Text = "Start"
        Else
            blRunning = True
            start_btn.Text = "Stop"
        End If
        Timer1.Enabled = blRunning
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: well yeah you got exactly my point but actually i need to be able to start and stop the timer anytime i want.. and the task i was given is to use timer not thread ...

Comment: The problem is that while the program is running, there will be no way to click the start or stop buttons, except for while the timer is running in between runs. If this is acceptable, then I will modify my code to show how to use a timer to start or stop the processing.

Comment: Alright, I updated the code. Be aware that without using a thread your program will still be unresponsive while running. You could try to add a label somewhere that will be populated with text such as 'Running' or 'Sleeping', or something similar. That way you can know when you can click the start/stop button.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `BackgroundWorker`. Even comes with free cancellation support.

Comment: @Steven Liekens, I agree with using threads or background workers for this. However, he stated that he was given a task to use a timer, not a thread (or background worker).

Comment: Can't he use both? If this is homework, I'd do it anyway. :-)

Comment: Notiçe that there is also a `System.Threading.Timer` which uses background threads under the covers. Perhaps the assignment was to use that timer instead of the windows forms timer.